# Please tell me how to make UI that follows the character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(in Unity 3D)

Hi.

I want to show "HPBar" of the character on UI Canvas.

I tried the following method, but it didn't work normally.

Please tell me how to solve this problem...

[image: Main Camera Inspector][image: UI Camera Inspector][image: UI Canvas Inspector]

```
/// <summary>
/// Follow target's position
/// </summary>
/// <param name="target">target(character's world position)</param>
void ChaseCharacter(Vector3 target)
{
    // change world position to screen position (Main Camera)
    Vector3 p1 = _worldCam.WorldToScreenPoint(target);

    // change screen position to world position (UI Camera)
    Vector3 p2 = _uiCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(p1);

    // Apply UI Position
    transform.position = p2;
}
```

Comment: Are you working in 2D and you want the HP bar always on player but inside the canvas?

Comment: @Leoverload
Yes. I think Arknights can be an example.

Comment: this can help you https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-get-ui-text-to-follow-a-character.377635/

Comment: Do you have an specific reason for using two cameras? I'd suggest you use the `worldCam` for the `Canvas`, and remove the `ScreenToWorldPoint` line on your code, so that `transform.position = p1`.

Comment: @Aboud
Camera are tow in this question forum, but my project use 4 cameras...

Comment: @Leoverload
I will read the link you gave me.
First of all, thank you before I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built a minimal example, with a single camera. I guess with some small tweaks it should work on your multi-camera case.

```
public class UIFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public Vector2 offset;

    new private Camera camera;
    
    void Start()
    {
        camera = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>().worldCamera;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ((RectTransform)transform).anchoredPosition = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(target.transform.position) + (Vector3)offset;
    }
}
```

`UIFollow` is a Component on the "HealthBar" object inside the `Canvas`. Make sure it's anchors are set to the left bottom corner.

[image]

The `offset` vector is used to place the health bar above the object's center, it's public so it's easier to modify while designing the game.

[image]

Comment: It seems to created orthographic camera.
My project is used perspective camera both (main, ui)

Comment: It works in Perspective as well: https://i.imgur.com/wcpbYfR.gif

Answer (score 0):

From the hierarchy tab, add a new object, section UI then select Image, a canvas object should appear if not already created, inside should be the white image created , this Image should already follow your camera to every place because its in the UI screen section not near the player, just resize, make transparent and add your health bar inside it.

Comment: this will not work if the character is moving freely in the environment or has a bit of dead zone from the camera

Comment: You are correct this will not work if the purpose is to have a health bar for each caracter as commonly seen in a tower defense game, but it will work if you have game like gta were the ui is always in the same pos

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your advice.
I solved this problem, but I don't know how it was solved.
I'll upload the resolved code.

```
Vector3 p1 = _worldCam.WorldToScreenPoint(target);
p1.z = 100;
Vector3 p2 = _uiCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(p1);
transform.position = p2;
```